# Do we need to create Class file for page of website in Asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am newbie and learning Asp.net. I am building as web application(admin panel) which will interact with the db. Earlier, when I created web application for assignments, I wrote the code for insert/delete etc in code behind of asp pages either using a sqldatasource or manually writing the code. Now, I am learning to use Ajax/Jquery and JSon for crud operations for a aspx page and have seen a class file being created(youtube video). I am confused as to why class file was created. What's the purpose ? Is it a good practice to create classes for aspx pages.

I created class files for winforms in C#. I am totally confused.I read MSDN but did not understand the purpose of Entity framework in terms of benefits.

Please help me with some information.

Comment: It's worth noting that webforms is a dying technology. You'll be better off learning web development using an MVC framework such as ASP .NET MVC.

Comment: Yes, that's next on the list but will be learning on my own. Asp.net is part of the curriculum so I have to learn. So do I need to create classes or no ?Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main benefit and motive behind having separate class behind page to avail the decoupling of HTML code and C# code. It is also little bit decoupled. For example if you have one guy working on HTML side and one coder is doing the server side, just imagine how both of these guys can work at the same time. So now one coder work on .cs file independently and HTML coder keep on evolving the look and feel.

Entity Framework is nothing a wrapper on the database interaction and help you to reduce the line of code you write to make the connection to the database and do the operation , but no body is forcing you to use it. It is just one of the best practice from purpose of better maintainability.

Comment: Thank you very much for clarifying in simple words. Since I am the only one working both codes so it does not matter is I work from code behind.
I am struggling a bit with EF concept, I understand its purpose but when retrieving data from multiple tables,I struggle. I will keep trying to practice. Thank you again.